# Convert large wav file to text in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I already tried this code to convert my large *wav* file to text

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

hellow=sr.AudioFile('hello_world.wav')
with hellow as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

But it is not converting it accurately, the reason I feel it's the 'US' accent.
Please tell me how i can convert whole large *wav* file accurately.

Comment: you can use project plyer: https://github.com/kivy/plyer

Comment: there are different module and library  all over the internet , but i highly doubt if there is even one can do "100% accurately" convert ,  it could worth millions of dollars and dozens of PhD paper.  so do not expect too much....

Comment: @bigdataolddriver please at least suggest which is best.

Comment: speech recolonization is  highly language dependent,  one of the [best  and open source speech recolonization sdk I know](https://github.com/Baidu-AIP/java-sdk) . it is for Chinese, probably not you need  since you care about 'US accent'

Answer (score 0):

Google's speech to text is very effective, try the below link,

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

You can choose the language (English US in your case) and also upload files.

Like @bigdataolddriver commented 100% accuracy is not possible yet, and will be worth millions.

Google speech to text has three types of APIs

Synchronous, Asynchronous and streaming, in which asynchronous allows you to ~480 minutes audio conversion while others will only let you ~1 minute. Following is the sample code to do the conversion.

```
filepath = "~/audio_wav/"     #Input audio file path
output_filepath = "~/Transcripts/" #Final transcript path
bucketname = "callsaudiofiles" #Name of the bucket created in the step before

# Import libraries
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import os
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
import wave
from google.cloud import storage
```

Speech to text support wav files with LINEAR16 or MULAW encoded audio.

Below is the code to get the frame rate and channel with code.

```
def frame_rate_channel(audio_file_name):
    with wave.open(audio_file_name, "rb") as wave_file:
        frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
        channels = wave_file.getnchannels()
        return frame_rate,channels
```

and the code below is the does the asynchronous conversion.

```
def google_transcribe(audio_file_name):

    file_name = filepath + audio_file_name

    # The name of the audio file to transcribe

    frame_rate, channels = frame_rate_channel(file_name)

    if channels > 1:
        stereo_to_mono(file_name)

    bucket_name = bucketname
    source_file_name = filepath + audio_file_name
    destination_blob_name = audio_file_name

    upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)

    gcs_uri = 'gs://' + bucketname + '/' + audio_file_name
    transcript = ''

    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=frame_rate,
    language_code='en-US')

    # Detects speech in the audio file
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
    response = operation.result(timeout=10000)

    for result in response.results:
        transcript += result.alternatives[0].transcript

    delete_blob(bucket_name, destination_blob_name)
    return transcript
```

and this is how you write them to file

```
def write_transcripts(transcript_filename,transcript):
    f= open(output_filepath + transcript_filename,"w+")
    f.write(transcript)
    f.close()
```

Kindly let me know if you need any further clarifications.